# RFID Door Lock Coding Errors

Tags: rfid, home-automation

I am trying to recreate an RFID door lock that I saw on the Arduino project hub but have ran into several issues. I had to manipulate the code slightly to make sure it was including the correct libraries and I think that solved some issues but not all. If anyone could take a look at my code and help me out that'd be awesome, I am pretty new with coding and need all the help I can get.
Thank you!

Here are the error messages I receive when trying to upload the code to my arduino:
Arduino: 1.8.8 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

```
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:66:17: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 #define SDA_D1O 9
                 ^
/Users/gavinmiles/Documents/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system.ino:70:9: note: in expansion of macro 'SDA_D1O'
 MFRC522(SDA_D1O, RESET_D1O); 
         ^
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:66:17: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
 #define SDA_D1O 9
                 ^
/Users/gavinmiles/Documents/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system.ino:70:9: note: in expansion of macro 'SDA_D1O'
 MFRC522(SDA_D1O, RESET_D1O); 
         ^
/Users/gavinmiles/Documents/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system.ino: In function 'void setup()':
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:120:10: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
   MFRC522.initial();
          ^
/Users/gavinmiles/Documents/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system/rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system.ino: In function 'void loop()':
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:137:12: error: 'class MFRC522' has no member named 'isCard'
   if( rfid.isCard() )
            ^
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:141:16: error: 'class MFRC522' has no member named 'readCardSerial'
       if( rfid.readCardSerial() )
                ^
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:152:33: error: 'class MFRC522' has no member named 'serNum'
               Serial.print(rfid.serNum[i], HEX);
                                 ^
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:154:30: error: 'class MFRC522' has no member named 'serNum'
               lcd.print(rfid.serNum[i],HEX);
                              ^
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:165:42: error: 'class MFRC522' has no member named 'serNum'
               if( My_RFID_Tag[i] != rfid.serNum[i] )
                                          ^
rfid_based_door_automatic_management_system:274:8: error: 'class MFRC522' has no member named 'halt'
   rfid.halt();
        ^
Multiple libraries were found for "LiquidCrystal.h"
 Used: /Users/gavinmiles/Documents/Arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal
 Not used: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/LiquidCrystal
Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"
 Used: /Users/gavinmiles/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Servo
 Not used: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Servo
exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/Users/gavinmiles/Downloads/untitled_file.ino
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

```
/* 
 *  RFID Module RC522
 *  Simple Project:- Arduino will read RFID Tag and Display To the Serial Monitor!
 *  
 *  RFID RC522 and Arduino Uno Pin Configuration
 *  
 *  RFID RC522          Arduino Uno
 *  SS/SDA              D10
 *  SCK                 D13
 *  MOSI                D11
 *  MISO                D12
 *  IRQ                 Not Connected
 *  GND                 GND
 *  RST                 D9
 *  3.3V                3.3V
 *  
 *  //Note: We connected LCD to the Analog Pins.
 *  Remember, Analog Pins can be act as a Digital Pins,
 *  But Digital Pins CAN NOT be act as a Analog Pins.
 *  
 *  LCD(16x2) Connections
 *  
 *  VSS pin to GND
 *  VCC pin to 5V
 *  //We are connecting "Contrast pin to GND for Maximum Brightness"
 *  //You can also connect it to 10K Pot if you wish to change the Brightness Of LCD.
 *  VEE pin to GND 
 *  RS pin to Analog pin A0
 *  R/W pin to ground
 *  Enable pin to Analog pin A1
 *  D4 pin to Analog pin 5
 *  D5 pin to Analog pin 4
 *  D6 pin to Analog pin 3
 *  D7 pin to Analog pin 2
 *  LED+ pin to POWER
 *  LED- pin to GND 
 *   
 *  Servo is Connected to Digital Pin 5  
 *  
 *  RGB LED
 *  From RGB LED, We need Only Red and Green Color, 
 *  So we are not connecting Blue pin of the RGB. 
 *  
 *  Red pin to Digital pin 6
 *  Green pin to Digital pin 7
 *  
 *  Buzzer to Digital pin 8
 * 
 *  
 *  Note:- RFID uses SPI Protocol to transfer the information.
 *  I took the Melody(for the Buzzer) from, 
 *  File -> Examples -> Digital -> ToneMelody
*/

//Include sections
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include "pitches.h"

//Define Component to Arduino Pins
/* Define the DIO used for the SDA (SS) and RST (reset) pins. */
#define SDA_D1O 9
#define RESET_D1O 8

/* Create an instance of the RFID library */
MFRC522(SDA_D1O, RESET_D1O); 
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9

#define SERVO_PIN 5

#define Red_LED 6
#define Green_LED 7

#define Buzzer 8


//initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5);
Servo DoorLock;
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN );

//Unique ID of RFID Tag, which you want to give access. 
int My_RFID_Tag[5] = {0x58,0x76,0x17,0x10,0x29};

//variable to hold your Access_card
boolean My_Card = false;  

// notes in the melody, taken from:
//File -> Examples -> Digital -> ToneMelody
int melody[] = {
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3, 0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:
int noteDurations[] = {
  4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
};

void setup() 
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //set the pins as an input/output
  pinMode(Red_LED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Green_LED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Buzzer,OUTPUT);

  //Servo Connnected to pin Digital Pin 5
  DoorLock.attach(SERVO_PIN);
  //open the serial port at 9600 baudrate.
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  //Initialise the LCD to 16x2 Character Format
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  //Initialise Servo and RFID
  SPI.begin();
  MFRC522.initial();
}

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  //First Assume detected card(Or tag) is My_Card, 
  //Then later we will check is it My_Card or not! 
  My_Card = true; 
  DoorLock.write(0); //Servo at 0 Position, Door is Closed.
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Robodia Technology");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("gy Solutions!");

  //Check if any RFID Tags Detected or not?
  if( rfid.isCard() )
  {
      //if RFID Tag is detected, check for the Unique ID,
      //and print it on the Serial Window
      if( rfid.readCardSerial() )
      {   
          lcd.clear();      
          lcd.print("UNIQUE ID is:- ");
          delay(500);          
          lcd.setCursor(0,1); //Set LCD Cursor to Second Row, First Character

      //Unique id is 5 Digit Number.
          //Printing in HEX for better Understanding
          for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
          {
              Serial.print(rfid.serNum[i], HEX);
              Serial.print(" ");              
              lcd.print(rfid.serNum[i],HEX);
              lcd.print(" ");                            
          }  
          delay(500);

      //Compare this RFID Tag Unique ID with your My_RFID_Tag's Unique ID
          for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          {   
              //if any one Unique ID Digit is not matching,
              //then make My_Card = false and come out from loop
              //No need to check all the digit!
              if( My_RFID_Tag[i] != rfid.serNum[i] )
              {
                My_Card = false;
                break;                
              }           
          }
          Serial.println(); 
          delay(1000); 

          //If RFID Tag is My_Card then give access to enter into room
          //else dont open the door.
          if(My_Card)
          {
            Serial.println("\nWelcome To Your Room, Robodia!");
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print("Welcome to Your");
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print("Room, Robodia!");
            delay(2000);                        

            //Turn on the Green LED as an indication of permission is given 
            //to access the room.
            digitalWrite(Green_LED,HIGH);

            //Buzzer Config, taken from:
            //File -> Examples -> Digital -> ToneMelody
            // iterate over the notes of the melody:
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 2)
            {
              for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 12; thisNote++) 
              {          
                // to calculate the note duration, take one second
                // divided by the note type.
                //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
                int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations[thisNote];
                tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);                        
                // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
                // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
                int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
                delay(pauseBetweenNotes);              
                // stop the tone playing:
                noTone(8);
              }
              i =  i + 1;
              delay(500);              
            }
            delay(1000);            

            //Now, Open the Door with the help of Servo Motor
            DoorLock.write(180);            
            delay(200);
            lcd.clear();                                    
            lcd.print("Door is Open");
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print("Now!");
            delay(2000);
            lcd.clear();

            //Give 10 Sec delay to enter into room
            //After that door will again closed!
            for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
            {
              lcd.print("Door will close");
              lcd.setCursor(0,1);
              lcd.print("in ");
              lcd.print(i);
              lcd.print(" Sec.HurryUp!");
              delay(1000);
              lcd.clear();
            }

            //Now,Door is closed and Green LED is Turned-Off.
            DoorLock.write(0);
            digitalWrite(Green_LED,LOW);
            delay(200);
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print("Door is Close");
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print("Now!");
            delay(2000);                            
          }

          // If RFID Tag is not My_Card then
          // Do not open the Door and 
          //Turn-On Red LED and Buzzer as an indication of Warning:
          //Somebody else is trying to enter into your room. 
          else
          {
            Serial.println("\nGet Out of Here !");
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print("Card isNOT FOUND!");
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print("Get Out of Here!");

            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
              digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
              digitalWrite(Red_LED,HIGH);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(Buzzer, LOW);
              digitalWrite(Red_LED,LOW);
              delay(500);              
            }
            delay(1000);            
          }                 
      }      
   }
  //Put RFID Reader into Halt, untill it not detects any RFID Tag.
  rfid.halt();
}
```

Comment: How about adding a link to the original project and some more information of a) your modifications and b) your issues? "Here's my code, tell me what's wrong" isn't really nice - and it does not comply to the rules of this forum.

Comment: you say `RFID Door Lock Coding Errors` and `solved some issues but not all`..... are we supposed to guess what the errors and the issues are?

Comment: I will find the original post and post the link. Sorry for the lack of information, I'm new to the site. Sorry if the original post came off as rude mic those weren't my intentions. Just looking for help and thought I'd ask if anyone could take a look at it and see what I missed. Thank you

Comment: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/user8523373/rfid-based-automatic-door-system-7b2065?ref=platform&ref_id=424_popular__intermediate_&offset=30 here is the link to the original project. All I've done is change out the rfid library for the MFRC522 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had seen many errors in your code. Some of them are as follows

1. `MFRC522.initial();` replace it with `rfid.initial();`
2. Libraries such as liquidcrystal, servo are default libraries in arduino so if you had download them from external source and copied them in your library folder please remove them.
3. This logic won't help as if the first id didn't match it will break the loop and and comparison won't go further with other and your will always find false as a result in this case.

   ```
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {   
         //if any one Unique ID Digit is not matching,
         //then make My_Card = false and come out from loop
         //No need to check all the digit!
         if( My_RFID_Tag[i] != rfid.serNum[i] ) // suggested change if( My_RFID_Tag[i] == rfid.serNum[i] )
         {
           My_Card = false;//My_Card = true
           break;                
         }           
     }
   ```
4. Library functions used in code are different from those available in library, open library file and search for those function used for same purpose.
5. Remove them

   ```
   #define SDA_D1O 9
   #define RESET_D1O 8
   MFRC522(SDA_D1O, RESET_D1O);
   ```

   you are already defining them and using them here in your code

   ```
   #define SS_PIN 10
   #define RST_PIN 9
   MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN );
   ```